# Getting an error when trying to validate fields that depend on another option using jQuery Validate plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate for a form. I need to add some functionality so an additional field is required if a specific option is selected from a select/drop-down menu.

Here's the example they provide on the jQuery website to require a certrain field if an option is checked in a checkbox (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     contact: {
       required: true,
       email: {
         depends: function(element) {
           return $("#contactform_email:checked")
         }
       }
     }
   }
})
```

I have it working where it will display the additional fields if a particular option is selected. Once the select menu loses focus, the following error appears in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
>   'call' of undefined

I have an example posted on JSFiddle. If someone could take a look I would greatly appreciate it. I need to get this working ASAP!

http://jsfiddle.net/2EfPZ/

Comment: Do you have the validate plugin source included?  http://jsfiddle.net/2EfPZ/13/

Comment: The example shown in the jQuery docs is currently wrong as it shows the example above but the code that works is @Andrew's below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed your fiddle (and simplified it a bit):

http://jsfiddle.net/2EfPZ/21/

Due to the awesomeness of:

```
ignore: ':hidden'
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is occurring because you need to associate the `depends` function with a particular validation rule:

```
$form.validate({
    rules: {
        favoriteSport: {
            required: true
        },
        position: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#favoriteSport').val() === '1';
                }
            }
        },
        player: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#favoriteSport").val() === '1';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        favoriteSport: "You must select a favorite sport",
        position: "You must select a position because you selected football",
        player: "You must select a player because you selected football"
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2EfPZ/20/